# If you don't put in the comments in the css file for a new WordPress theme will it still work?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm at work so I can't really make a theme or delete content in a CSS file to see what happens; but I am curious. Why do all the tutorials tell you to put comments in you theme development? Can you just skip that step if you are not going to be making your theme available for the general public to use?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. 

The reason why tutorials tell you to put comments in your theme, is so that others can read and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It's usefull to later see what you have written, otherwise your code becomes sloppy but no it isn't neccesary for the code to work.